# A confusion regarding the statement about Tarski's Fixed Point Theorem

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As title suggests, I have a thought about Tarski's Fixed Point Theorem.

The statement of the theorem I was given was that:

> Suppose $X$ is a set and $f:\wp(X)\to\wp(X)$ is an increasing function (with respect to containment) then $\exists Z\in \wp(X)$ such that $f(Z)=Z.$

I understood that prove that was given. However, I was thinking couldn't we just take $Z=\emptyset$ then we have $f(\emptyset)=f(Z)=\emptyset=Z$? (thus the result becomes trivial?)

Or should we add that $Z$ must be non-empty?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Of possible interest is the discussion of "Fixed Points of Monotone Closure Operators" (do a search-in-page search for this phrase) in the first part of my 3-part answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/342205/15780).

Comment: $f$ is pre-given, so you don't know what $f(\emptyset)$ is. The increasingness implies that $f(\emptyset) \subseteq f(A)$ for any $A$, because $\emptyset \subseteq A$, nothing more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $X=\Bbb N$, and take $f(Z)=Z\cup\{42\}$. Why is $\varnothing$ a fixed point? It's not. $f(\varnothing)=\{42\}\neq\varnothing$.

Or for example, $f(Z)=Z\cup\{\min\{n\in\Bbb N\mid n\notin Z\}\}$, i.e. always add the smallest element not in $Z$. No finite iteration of $f$ from $\varnothing$ is a fixed point.